# How to use DrawableGameComponent in Silverlight + XNA?

Tags: c#, silverlight, xna, silverlight-4.0, xna-4.0

I'm making a project to Windows Phone using Silverlight + XNA, but I don't know how I can use the `DrawableGameComponent` because the constructor requires a `Game` class, it looks like this:

**Planet.cs**

```
class Planet : DrawableGameComponent
{
    public Planet(Game game): base(game){

    {
}
```

but in my first page of Silverlight and XNA project not is a `Game` class it's this:

**GamePage.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class GamePage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
   ...
}
```

Where do I find the `Game` class to pass into the `DrawableGameComponent` constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yap, I know, there is no `Game` object, or `GameComponents` in a combined Silverlight and XNA application.

I've found another implementations of those classes (such as `GameComponent`, `DrawableGameComponent`, `IDrawable`...) on Microsoft XNA Community Game Platform that I use everytime in Silverlight+XNA, but I don't remember where so I can't give you a link. If you can give me your email I'll send them to you, or I can try to paste the whole 7 classes code here if you prefer.

Comment: thanks much man, but desist of make in Silverlight and XNA, make in XNA, have litle documentation about that, sameanyway thanks for enlighten me man, thanks much.